# YYYY-mm-dd Form validation in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, formvalidation-plugin

How to Done Date form Validation in Codeigniter,

I tried Like this,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pastdate_start', 'Date of birth',
     'regex_match[(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}]');
```

But I got

> function Preg-match No ending matching delimiter ')' found

these error,how to solve it,please give me solution.

What mistake in my coding?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pastdate_start','Date of birth','required|regex_match[/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]((?:19|20)\d\d),pastdate_start');
```

Comment: Its CodeIgniter issue.. as we use ` | ` in preg match pattern, the codeIgniter consider it as separator between to validators like `required`|`valid_email`. but i think you should make a callback function for validation.

Comment: `$this->form_validation->set_rules('dob','Date of birth','required|callback_regexMatch[]'); `  and `$this->form_validation->set_message('regexMatch', '%s is not a valid.');` and callback function will like `function regexMatch($str){
   if (!preg_match("/^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}$/",$str)) {
    return FALSE;
   }
   return  TRUE;
  }`

Comment: Hi Manish,Thanx for ur reply,In that above coding just checking field empty or not but cant check that YYYY-MM-DD format Y?i writeen that function regxmatch in form validation in library folder its correct or not?

Comment: Don't write that function in form validation. just write callback function in the same controller in which you are validating the form. [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) use this link and find `Callbacks: Your own Validation Functions`